# Log Restangular POST Request Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, restangular

I am new to restangular. Searched several posts but did not find the content to which I am looking for.
This is an hybrid mobile app. development.
Query 1:

I have set up my BaseURL http://example.com/api/v1.
Now assuming I make the below request with data object as parameter.
How to console the request data to check what am sending ?
I tried
getRestangularUrl()
getRequestedUrl()
but both gives only the URL.

```
   var serviceLocator = Restangular.all('serviceLocator')
            return {
                serviceLocator: function (name) {
                    var data= {
                                "Name":name
                              }
                     return serviceLocator.post(data);
}
}
```

Query 2:

I have many requests already available in application.
Now, my erquirement is to enable more security i need to add 1 more parameter to each request that is being sent.Is there any global way to add this ?
I tried setDefaultRequestParams of Restangular but was unable to print the logs to verify it.

Comment: If you're in chrome you can try looking at the *Network Panel* in the Web Inspector (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#network-panel-overview) to debug the requests

Comment: @jpopesculian Thanks for the reply .. I am developing hybrid application .. I am curious to get that printed in console .. Is there any way to log this ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#addrequestinterceptor?